# numpy: efficiently reading a large array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, large-files

I have a binary file that contains a dense `n*m` matrix of 32-bit floats. What's the most efficient way to read it into a Fortran-ordered `numpy` array?

The file is multi-gigabyte in size. I get to control the format, but it must be compact (i.e. about `4*n*m` bytes in length) and must be easy to produce from non-Python code.

**edit**: It is imperative that the method produces a Fortran-ordered matrix directly (due to the size of the data, I can't afford to create a C-ordered matrix and then transform it into a separate Fortran-ordered copy.)

Comment: Does http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/InputOutput answer your question? (See section on  "binary files")

Comment: @nimrodm Thanks. In fact, I've already been experimenting with some of the methods described there. I am asking the question in the hope that someone would come forward who either has first-hand experience doing what I am trying to do, or is familiar with `numpy` internals and can advise from that angle.

Comment: Generally I've found when reading very large arrays into numpy that I need to know the size in advance, in order to pre-allocate the appropriate array to hold the data.  Do you know the size in advance?  If not, try using a two-pass approach: first scan to discover size/dimensions of data, then allocate array, then read/parse into that array.

Comment: @Peter Good point, thanks. I do know the size in advance (I control the data format, so I can write out the size as part of the file header.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NumPy provides [`fromfile()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) to read binary data.

```
a = numpy.fromfile("filename", dtype=numpy.float32)
```

will create a one-dimensional array containing your data.  To access it as a two-dimensional Fortran-ordered `n x m` matrix, you can reshape it:

```
a = a.reshape((n, m), order="FORTRAN")
```

[EDIT: The `reshape()` actually copies the data in this case (see the comments).  To do it without cpoying, use

```
a = a.reshape((m, n)).T
```

Thanks to Joe Kingtion for pointing this out.]

But to be honest, if your matrix has several gigabytes, I would go for a HDF5 tool like [h5py](http://h5py.alfven.org/) or [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/moin).  Both of the tools have FAQ entries comparing the tool to the other one.  I generally prefer h5py, though PyTables seems to be more commonly used (and the scopes of both projects are slightly different).

[HDF5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format#Interfaces) files can be written from most programming language used in data analysis.  The list of interfaces in the linked Wikipedia article is not complete, for example there is also an [R interface](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hdf5/index.html).  But I actually don't know which language you want to use to write the data...

Comment: @Sven Thanks. What would you say are the advantages of using HDF5 over a simple `n*m` array for storing one large dense matrix of floats?

Comment: @aix: to name a few: the ability of transparently having only part of the matrix in memory of a given time, the ability of transparent compression and meta-data taking care of the matrix dimensions, eliminating an important source of erros.  And since it is really easy to use, I don't see real disadvantages.

Comment: @Sven Could you also clarify something in your example. If I do `a = numpy.fromfile("filename", dtype=numpy.float32)` followed by `a = a.reshape((n, m), order="FORTRAN")` on a 4GB file, is this potentially going to create a 4GB "C" matrix in memory only to immediately make another 4GB in-memory copy to flip it into the Fortran format?

Comment: @aix - Rehshaping doesn't copy the array, it just returns a new view of it.  There's no duplication of memory in that case.

Comment: @Joe Even flipping between C and Fortran formats (row-wise vs column-wise **storage**)? How's that possible?

Comment: @aix - It just changes the striding of the array. It doesn't actually make it Fortran ordered in memory.

Comment: @Joe Do you have any links for where I can read up on this? This goes contrary to my intuition and seems to completely negate the point.

Comment: @aix - Woops, sorry, I was wrong about that... If you change the order on reshaping, it does create a copy that actually is the order you specify.  Generally speaking, though, reshaping and transposing arrays doesn't copy them.

Comment: @Joe No problem. I know that changing the shape of a `numpy` matrix doesn't copy the data. However, for performance reasons I do care about how stuff gets stored in memory, and I can't afford to have two copies of the same multi-gigabyte matrix around, hence all my questions.

Comment: @aix - For what it's worth, you don't need to specify the order and create the copy. Just do `a = np.fromfile(...)` and then `a = a.reshape((m,n)).T`.  This won't create a copy and has exactly the same effect.

Comment: @Joe - sorry, you lost me again. As I stated in my question, I am looking for the matrix to be Fortran-ordered. Now, let's say for the sake of argument that `np.fromfile()` gives a `C` matrix (does it? can I change that?) Now, `reshape` changes the striding. I assume that the transpose also works by changing the striding (or am I wrong here?) So the end result is still a `C` matrix, no?

Comment: @aix - I'm assuming that you're reading in a Fortran ordered array from disk.  You get a flat array that is actually a ixj Fortran ordered array.  This is the same as a jxi C-ordered array, except that it's transposed.  So, we reshape it as jxi, and then transpose it to be ixj.  Numpy thinks it's C-ordered jxi being viewed as ixj, but that's equivalent to being directly stored as Fortran ordered ixj in memory.

Comment: @Joe - yes, but this goes back to my original question. How do I efficiently read a binary file into a **Fotran** matrix? Are you saying that `np.fromfile()` does that? There's nothing in the documentation, and no parameters that I could find that control this.

Comment: @aix - It is in Fortran order in memory... The only difference is numpy's flags... If you were to access the memory buffer of the numpy array from Fortran, you'd read it direcly as a ixj array.  `np.fromfile` will read it in in the order that it's stored as on disk. Like I said, I was assuming that it was already stored on disk in Fortran order. If you want to write a C-ordered array to disk as a Fortran ordered array just use `a.ravel('F').tofile(fid)`.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for taking the time to explain this. It is now perfectly clear. I get to control the writing of the file, so I can ensure it's written in the desired order. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Numpy stores the arrays as flat vectors. The multiple dimensions are just an illusion created by different views and strides that the Numpy iterator uses.

For a thorough but easy to follow explanation how Numpy internally works, see the excellent [chapter 19 on The Beatiful Code book](http://books.google.fi/books?id=gJrmszNHQV4C&lpg=PA307&ots=rLSYuyRaoj&dq=beautiful%20code%20numpy%20iterators&hl=fi&pg=PA303#v=onepage&q=beautiful%20code%20numpy%20iterators).

At least Numpy `array()` and `reshape()` have an argument for C ('C'), Fortran ('F') or preserved order ('A').
Also see the question [How to force numpy array order to fortran style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688304/how-to-force-numpy-array-order-to-fortran-style)

### An example with the default C indexing ([row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)):

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4) # <- C order by default
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> a[1]
array([4, 5, 6, 7])

>>> a.strides
(32, 8)
```

### Indexing using Fortran order ([column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-major_order)):

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4, order='F')
>>> a
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11]])
>>> a[1]
array([ 1,  4,  7, 10])

>>> a.strides
(8, 24)
```

---

### The other view

Also, you can always get the other kind of view using the parameter T of an array:

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4, order='C')
>>> a.T
array([[ 0,  4,  8],
       [ 1,  5,  9],
       [ 2,  6, 10],
       [ 3,  7, 11]])

>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4, order='F')
>>> a.T
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

---

### You can also manually set the strides:

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4, order='C')
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> a.strides
(32, 8)
>>> a.strides = (8, 24)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11]])
```