# How to do in place Cholesky factorization in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to do an in place Cholesky factorization, but either that feature is not actually implemented in scipy or there is something I am not understanding.  I am posting here in case it is the latter.  Here is a simplified example of what I'm doing:

```
import numpy
import scipy.linalg

numpy.random.seed(0)
X = numpy.random.normal(size=(10,4))
V = numpy.dot(X.transpose(),X)
R = V.copy()
scipy.linalg.cholesky(R,False,overwrite_a=True)
print V
print R
```

I think what should happen is for R to be overwritten with an upper triangular matrix.  However, when I run this code, my V and R come out identical (cholesky is not overwriting R).  Am I misunderstanding the purpose of overwrite_a, or making some other mistake?  If this is just a bug in scipy, is there a workaround or another way I can do an in place Cholesky factorization in Python?

Comment: See http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/872

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are brave enough you can avoid `scipy` and go for a low-level call to `linalg.lapack_lite.dpotrf`

```
import numpy as np

# prepare test data
A = np.random.normal(size=(10,10))
A = np.dot(A,A.T)
L = np.tril(A)

# actual in-place cholesky
assert L.dtype is np.dtype(np.float64)
assert L.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']
n, m = L.shape
assert n == m
result = np.linalg.lapack_lite.dpotrf('U', n, L, n, 0)
assert result['info'] is 0

# check if L is the desired L cholesky factor
assert np.allclose(np.dot(L,L.T), A)
assert np.allclose(L, np.linalg.cholesky(A))
```

You have to understand lapack's [DPOTRF](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dpotrf.f), fortran calling conventions, memory layout. Don't forget upon exit to check `result['info'] == 0`. Nevertheless you see its just a line of code, and by throwing away all sanity checks and copying done by `linalg.cholesky` this could also be more efficient.

Comment: I've been looking for an example of how to do that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try it again, with

```
>>> scipy.__version__
'0.11.0'
>>> np.__version__
'1.6.2'
```

it works perfectly:

```
X = np.random.normal(size=(10,4))
V = np.dot(X.transpose(),X)
print V
R = V.copy()
print R
C = scipy.linalg.cholesky(R,False,overwrite_a=True)
print V
print R
```

Output is:

```
[[ 11.22274635   5.10611692   0.70263037   3.14603088] # V before
 [  5.10611692   8.94518939  -3.17865941   1.64689675]
 [  0.70263037  -3.17865941   7.35385131  -2.23948391]
 [  3.14603088   1.64689675  -2.23948391   8.25112653]]
[[ 11.22274635   5.10611692   0.70263037   3.14603088] # R before
 [  5.10611692   8.94518939  -3.17865941   1.64689675]
 [  0.70263037  -3.17865941   7.35385131  -2.23948391]
 [  3.14603088   1.64689675  -2.23948391   8.25112653]]
[[ 11.22274635   5.10611692   0.70263037   3.14603088] # V after
 [  5.10611692   8.94518939  -3.17865941   1.64689675]
 [  0.70263037  -3.17865941   7.35385131  -2.23948391]
 [  3.14603088   1.64689675  -2.23948391   8.25112653]]
[[ 3.35003677  1.52419728  0.20973811  0.93910339] # R after
 [ 0.          2.57332704 -1.35946252  0.08375069]
 [ 0.          0.          2.33703292 -0.99382158]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          2.52478036]]
```

Comment: Strange, it still doesn't work on mine (even copy-pasted your exact code).  What scipy and numpy versions are you using? Mine are 0.11.0 and 1.6.2, respectively.

Comment: Oops, missed your version numbers in there.  I guess we have the same version.

Comment: @user1572508 I edited my answer to include them, they weren't there to begin with.

Comment: Well, I don't know what the issue is.  I tried reinstalling numpy and scipy and tried the same code on my macbook (instead of my Ubuntu machine) and keep getting the same results.  For now I am going to settle for a not in place factorization and move on.  If I figure out what's going on later I will post it.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, the following code based on Warren's comment solves the problem:

```
import numpy
import scipy.linalg

numpy.random.seed(0)
X = numpy.random.normal(size=(10,4))
V = numpy.dot(X.transpose(),X)
R = V.copy('F')
print V.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']
print R.flags['F_CONTIGUOUS']
scipy.linalg.cholesky(R,False,overwrite_a=True)
print V
print R
```

All I've done is change the underlying storage format of R from C order to Fortran order, which causes `overwrite_a` to behave as expected.

If your matrix is real valued you can do this without making a copy by simply passing the transpose to cholesky.  I don't think the transpose fix will work if your matrix is complex-valued, since the transpose of a complex hermitian matrix is not generally equal to its conjugate transpose.  However, if you make sure your matrix is using fortran order (`R.flags['F_CONTIGUOUS'] == True`) in the first place then you shouldn't have a problem.  But, see [Setting the *default* data order (C vs. Fortran) in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911041/setting-the-default-data-order-c-vs-fortran-in-numpy) for difficulties with that strategy.