# Memory usage doubled when passing matrix to shared object

Tags: python, numpy, shared-objects, f2py

I have a linear set of equations, where
A x = b and A is a large matrix and b is known as well.
The matrix A is set up with python.
Now I want to invert matrix A to get x.

A and b are passed to a Fortran 90 program via a shared object. I compiled the Fortran program using numpy.f2py:

```
import numpy.f2py.f2py2e as f2py2e
import sys, os
sys.argv += "-lmkl_rt -c -m MKL_MODULE MKL_WRAPPER.f90".split()
f2py2e.main()
```

Finally, I call the f90 subroutine:

```
MKL_MODULE.mkl_wrapper.call_dgelsd(A, b, np.shape(A)[0], np.shape(A)[1])
```

When calling the fortran program, the memory usage doubles, apparently due to an internal copy of the matrix A and b.
However, once I have the vector x I'm not interested in A or b anymore.
Is there any way to avoid that internal copy and passing A to the fortran program?

I already had the idea of saving A and b to the HD and reading it from the Fortran program, but this takes very long time and is not really an option for matrices of the size I'm dealing with.

Comment: Is the original array(s) `F` ordered?

Comment: No, its C ordered. But converting to F ordered should be no problem.

Comment: Converting from C order to F order requires a copy

Comment: That's true. I thought about setting up the array in F order immediatley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No internal copy will be made if the arrays are in F-order

[[How to force numpy array order to fortran style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688304/how-to-force-numpy-array-order-)
to-fortran-style][1]